# How to store lots of calendar dates

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

Users can select dates from a calendar to block. If I store each selected date as a record/row in my Calendar table, then there would be lots of stored rows/records. Is there a more efficient (less processing) way of doing this?

Comment: Please define "**lots of stored rows/records**".

Comment: Can you please explain to us more, it's a bit unclear what you want to achieve! If you have two models one for `Users` and one for storing the `Dates` with a one-to-many relationship, I would recommend that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if the user is going to block the date for everyone or just for themselves:

If they are blocking the date for every user that views it then it would be a good idea to store this in the Calendar model table, as every user will need to load this each time they load the calendar.

Or

If each user is blocking the date so only they can see that it is blocked, it is better to store the data in either the User model table or else as an association between the user and the calendar. This depends on how your calendar model is set up. If you wanted, you could have a column in the user table that stores data that represents all the dates that are blocked for that user. This will prevent the large number of rows you are talking about. This could be done with a JSON column in the User table. You could also store the data of which dates are blocked as a relation between the user and the calendar by creating a UsersCalendar table.

With a more detailed question we could give you a more detailed answer.